# MathJax element not responding to onclick event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, mathjax

I am working on a web page that includes MathJax elements, and I have implemented a toggle functionality using the onclick event for certain elements. The toggling works perfectly for regular HTML elements, but when I try to apply the same onclick event to a MathJax element, it doesn't seem to respond.

Here's a simplified version(MRE) of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .toggle {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    width:5cm;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.75);
    opacity:0.9;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .button {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['|', '|']],
    displayMath: []
  },
  options: {
    skipHtmlTags: [
      'script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 
      'code', 'annotation', 'annotation-xml'
    ],
    includeHtmlTags: {
      br: '\\n', wbr: '', '#comment': '', 'pre': ':'
    }
  }
};
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  menuSettings: {
    context: "Browser"
  }
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>Input Code</h2>
    <span>Some element</span>
    <span><span class="button" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red">|\color{red}\fbox{$\tau$}| vector</span>
    <span class="toggle" style="display:none;width=3cm;white-space:normal;">This is some paragraph describing the toogle variable</span>
    </span>
    <br>
    <script>
      toggleids = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
      for (let i = 0; i < toggleids.length; i++) {
        toggleids[i].id = "toggle " + (i + 1);
      }
    
      buttonids = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
      for (let i = 0; i < buttonids.length; i++) {
        buttonids[i].id = "button " + (i + 1);
        buttonids[i].addEventListener("click", showinfo);
      }
    
      function showinfo(event) {
        let buttonIndex = event.target.id.split(" ")[1];
        let toggleId = "toggle " + buttonIndex;   
        let toggleElement = document.getElementById(toggleId);
        toggleElement.style.display =
        toggleElement.style.display === "none" ? "inline-block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

The issue is that the onclick event works as expected for regular elements but doesn't seem to trigger for the MathJax element. Here, in element of class `button`, the event gets triggered when clicked on vector but not on the mathjax element. Is there a specific consideration or modification needed when dealing with MathJax elements and onclick events?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. Nothing to do with mathjax. Your way to get which button was clicked on is incorrect.

First of all, it is quite a bad style to rely on this id numbering: you need an absolute guarantee that there will be as many `.button` and `.toggle` elements, and that they are in the correct order.

And secondly, and more directly what happens here, your way of extacting the id number works only for flat elements

```
<span class=button><b>Hello</b> world</span>
```

would also work only if your click on "world" (that is on the button, to which you gave the numbered id), but not if you click on "hello". Because then "target" is the `<b>` element, to which you haven't set an ID (and that would be a bad idea of course, to set the same id on several elements).

You need to find another way to associate buttons and toggles span.

For example, if it cannot be with ad-hoc ids (obviously, you are doing all this, because you don't want to add yourself `id=...` in your html) you could enclose them in a common element, and then decide that child `.button` element toggle the sibbling `.toggle` element of the same parent.

One proposal

```js
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['|', '|']],
    displayMath: []
  },
  options: {
    skipHtmlTags: [
      'script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 
      'code', 'annotation', 'annotation-xml'
    ],
    includeHtmlTags: {
      br: '\\n', wbr: '', '#comment': '', 'pre': ':'
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  width:5cm;
  border:1px solid yellow;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.75);
  opacity:0.9;
  text-align:center;
}
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Input Code</h2>
    <span>Some element</span>
    <span class=pairButtonToggle><span class="button" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red">|\color{red}\fbox{$\tau$}| vector</span>
    <span class="toggle" style="display:none;width=3cm;white-space:normal;">This is some paragraph describing the toogle variable</span>
    </span>
    <br>
    <script>
        let pairs = document.getElementsByClassName("pairButtonToggle");
        for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            let buttons=pairs[i].getElementsByClassName("button");
            let toggles=pairs[i].getElementsByClassName("toggle");
            for(let b of buttons){
                b.addEventListener("click", ()=>showinfo(toggles));
            }
        }
    
        function showinfo(toggles) {
            for(let t of toggles){
                t.style.display = t.style.display === "none" ? "inline-block" : "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace 'target' with 'currentTarget' in your function. See what happens when your log the id's. CurrentTarget ensures to target the right element (the one which listens to the event)

```js
toggleids = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
      for (let i = 0; i < toggleids.length; i++) {
        toggleids[i].id = "toggle " + (i + 1);
      }
    
      buttonids = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
      for (let i = 0; i < buttonids.length; i++) {
        buttonids[i].id = "button " + (i + 1);
        buttonids[i].addEventListener("click", showinfo);
      }
    
      function showinfo(event) {
        let buttonIndex = event.currentTarget.id.split(" ")[1];
        console.log(event.currentTarget.id,event.target.id);
        let toggleId = "toggle " + buttonIndex;   
        let toggleElement = document.getElementById(toggleId);
        toggleElement.style.display =
        toggleElement.style.display === "none" ? "inline-block" : "none";
      }
```

```css
.toggle {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    width:5cm;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.75);
    opacity:0.9;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .button {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>


<h2>Input Code</h2>

    <span>Some element</span>
    <span><span class="button" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red">|\color{red}\fbox{$\tau$}| vector</span>
    <span class="toggle" style="display:none;width=3cm;white-space:normal;">This is some paragraph describing the toogle variable</span>
    </span>
    
    
    <script>
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['|', '|']],
    displayMath: []
  },
  options: {
    skipHtmlTags: [
      'script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 
      'code', 'annotation', 'annotation-xml'
    ],
    includeHtmlTags: {
      br: '\\n', wbr: '', '#comment': '', 'pre': ':'
    }
  }
};
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  menuSettings: {
    context: "Browser"
  }
});

</script>
```